# Fabric JS: How able to draw a object in canvas on existing canvas which renders PDF using PDFJS

Tags: fabricjs, pdf.js

Here, I'm trying to draw a object in the canvas which has rendered PDF using PDFJS. I was able to draw the rect by when I try to move the object the object is acting weird in the canvas.

I think there is not interaction between fabricJS and pdfJS. Kindly help me out with the issue

Here's the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/yesku5db/1/

Once the PDF is loaded move the mouse to the center of the pdf where you can see the mouse cursor changing and once you click it try to move the object the object goes to the top left of the canvas.

```
    //pdfjs stuff
var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf';
PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function (pdf) {
  pdf.getPage(1).then(function (page) {
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
    var canvas = document.getElementById('pdfcanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;
    page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport});
  });
});

//fabricjs stuff
var fcanvas = new fabric.Canvas("pdfcanvas", {selection: false});
fcanvas.setWidth(300);
fcanvas.setHeight(300);
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            fill: '#FF454F',
            opacity: 0.5,
            transparentCorners: true,
            borderColor: "gray",
            cornerColor: "gray",
            cornerSize: 5
        });
 fcanvas.add(rect);
 fcanvas.renderAll();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Implement like [this demo](https://github.com/RavishaHesh/PDFJsAnnotations/blob/master/pdfannotate.js) to load pdf files using pdf.js and render in fabricjs canvas.

Comment: if possible. Can you add it on fiddle @Durga